# How to disable Hardware Acceleration in Linux?

Tags: xorg, hardware, graphics, gpu, opengl

How can I turn off Hardware Acceleration in Linux, also known as Direct Rendering. I wish to turn this off, as it messes with some applications like OBS Studio which can't handle capturing of hardware acceleration on other applications since it's enabled for the entire system. Certain apps can turn it on and off, but can't do this for desktop and other apps.

When adding a source to capture from in OBS it just shows a blank capture image, for example if I wanted to record my desktop, it'll just show it as a blank capture input. Doesn't work if I want to capture web browser like Google Chrome, unless it's a single window with no tabs, and hardware acceleration is turned off in it's settings.

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.15.1 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz
       GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.90 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Comment: Try asking about a specific scenario, not something general like this. Like broadcasting a chrome window through X and OBS on some distribution with some video card and some module. Also refer to where you've set which setting off exactly. This helps people understand your setup.

Comment: @Zip Maybe you didn't read the question before properly and understand it. Check and try again, I have asked about a specific scenario, and that is to disable Hardware Acceleration for the whole system not just parts of it just for few applications.

Comment: Well, I did not explain myself appropriately. Applications will individually access hardware resources directly through the modules or through libs generally. I don't think there is a system wide simple switch for that. Anyway you don't mention your distro nor which drivers you're using, which may influence the answer. You seem to have issues with a very particular obs setup that may have an easier solution than what you asked, with the bonus that you may keep acceleration on for other stuff. Just ignore this from me if you disagree though, to keep comments clean...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure Xorg to disable OpenGL / GLX.

For a first try, you can run a second X session: switch to tty2, log in and type:

```
startx -- :2 vt2 -extension GLX
```

To permanently disable hardware acceleration, create a file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/disable-gpu.conf
```

with the the content:

```
Section "Extensions"
    Option "GLX" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Note that Xwayland in Wayland compositors like Gnome3-Wayland will ignore settings in `xorg.conf.d`.

Comment: That approach not working unfortunately on xubuntu 18, do you know how to do the same on modern xorg?

Comment: @IvanTalalaev Try to also disable extensions `DRI2` and `DRI3`.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work either. Let me clarify: in my system I have `xorg.conf.d` in `/usr/share/X11/` I placed there `disable-gpu.conf` file with required disable lines as depicted on image https://i.imgur.com/QKHzz6l.png that is right?

Comment: @IvanTalalaev The file looks correct. Change its name to `90-disable-gpu.conf` to make sure it is applied as the last one. Maybe another config overwrites it.

Comment: @IvanTalalaev Output of `xdpyinfo | head -n 60` shows you enabled X extensions.

Comment: many thanks for your reply! Definitely `xdpyinfo` shows that `GLX`, `DRI2` and `DRI3` still loaded, that means 90-disable-gpu.conf not loaded or probably not working. I dig over [documentation](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.html#toc5) and realized that `Disable` should be replaced with `off`, and all should be probably placed in `ServerLayout` section but that doesn't work either. Mind if I drop you a line outside stackexchange?

Comment: I have a few questions about x11docker as well actually)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84322/discussion-between-ivan-talalaev-and-mviereck).

Comment: @IvanTalalaev you put the file in the incorrect directory. It needs to be in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. `/usr/share` is not for local system configuration files.

Comment: @Mioriin thanks, but in my system xorg.conf.d located in the denoted place it's not mistake. Anyway I tried again -- doesn't work.

Comment: Please read `man xorg.conf` to see why changes to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` do not work.

Comment: @Mioriin could you give more meaningful comment rather than "read smth to understand why it doesn't work"

Comment: @Mioriin from `man xorg.conf` https://i.imgur.com/UYOfSys.png

Comment: `/usr/share` is reserved for package defaults and files in there should not be tampered with, in order to maintain at least one version of a default configuration to fallback to when tinkering. If you need a file from there, copy (or recreate) it to one of the other locations.

Comment: I have the same issue as @IvanTalalaev and there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d directory on my ubuntu 16 installation.

Comment: @latj You can create directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` yourself. Xorg will regard it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above didn't work for me. It caused an error on boot to the effect of `unw_get_proc_name failed`. I don't know if this happened for anyone else, but I found a different solution.

I modified `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`. For me, the file contained the following pre-edit:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "Accel" "off"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

I added a line below `Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"`: `Option "Accel" "off"`. Using this modification instead of the solution above, my system booted and `nvidia-smi` didn't show `Xorg` anymore.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This solution also removed from GPU memory sddm process and some other minor, freeing 600MB memory. On modern CPU user interface is as fast as on acceleration, thanks!