# Cinnamon crashes if I disable hardware acceleration

Tags: cinnamon

If I disable hardware acceleration like described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408592/148560) 
and reboot my Linux Mint machine, I get an error that Cinnamon crashed and that I'm running in fallback mode.

Does anyone know how I can make Cinnamon work without hardware acceleration?

Comment: are you using VM?

Comment: No, it's a ThinkPad x230 with intel i7 and intel HD4000 graphics.

Comment: Use vesa output.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Cinnamon have a special mode available without hardware acceleration on login.
You have to choose "Cinnamon (Software Rendering)" on login.