# Prevent Xorg from suspending when changing tty

Tags: linux, xorg, tty, chvt

I'm running two applications on two different ttys. Say application A runs on ttyA and application B runs on ttyB. If I switch from ttyA to ttyB I get the following message

`x-daemon[544]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch`.

So application A on ttyA, which obviously is a Xorg application, isn't updated anymore. This eventually causes my system to freeze due to a sort of memory leak as buffers in application A are not swapped anymore.

Question: Is it possible to keep refreshing X when the X server is not in the active tty?

I tried starting Xorg with `-novtswitch` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Xorg takes control over the GPU. If another tty takes control over the monitor, Xorg has to release the GPU. Applications that use GPU hardware acceleration (AIGLX clients mentioned in your log) are suspended because the GPU cannot be shared across different ttys or multiple X servers.

You can run Xorg without hardware acceleration at all, compare: [How to disable Hardware Acceleration in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408582/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-linux/408592#408592)

---

A possibility for single applications are untrusted cookies:

> You can forbid an application to have access to GPU with untrusted cookies. Example:
>   xauth -f $HOME/mycookie generate . untrusted
>   XAUTHORITY=$HOME/mycookie glxgears
>   glxgears will fail to start because it has no GPU access. Using trusted instead of untrusted allows GPU access, and glxgears works.

(From https://security.stackexchange.com/a/161342/132289)